# How to identify npm packages installed or not in my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular6, angular7

I am trying to find npm packages installed or not in my angular project using nodejs.
How to get installed packages from package.json to check this.
I have one array with packages.
Example:

```
var npmpackagesarr=["example-ng6-input","example-ng6-radio","example-ng6-combo"];

   for(var i=0;i<npmpackagesarr.length;i++){

    if(npmpackagesarr[i]=="????"){
      console.log("Hey..this package already installed");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Hey..this package not installed");
    }

   }
```

How can I identify above the array npm packages installed or not?

Comment: load both package-lock.json and package.json compare installed

Answer (score 0):

open your file project and check Package.json file or else check node_modules.

Comment: Can you try using nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

you can open Package.json and Look at the dependencies or use `npm install` for install all package in dependencies .

Answer (score 0):

use the JSON.parse on the Package.json and extract the dependencies key into an array. After that you can run indexOf on that array with the value you're looking for.

```
let data;
fetch('./Package.json').then(data => {
  data = Object.keys((JSON.parse(res)).dependencies);
})

search(array, package) {
  if(array.indexOf(package) !== -1) {
    // installed
  } else {
    // not installed message
  }
}

search(data, '@angular/core');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script to check if each package in a predefined list is both defined in `package.json` and installed.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const PACKAGES = ['aws-sdk', 'node-cache', 'example-ng6-input', 'lorem-hipsum'];

const readJSONFile = (name) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(name, 'utf8'));
  } catch (error) {
    return {};
  }
};

const isDepMissing = ({ name, json }) => {
  const d1 = json.dependencies || {};
  const d2 = json.devDependencies || {};
  return !(d1[name] || d2[name]);
};

const packageJSON = readJSONFile('package.json');
const packageLockJSON = readJSONFile('package-lock.json');

const notDefined = PACKAGES.filter(name => isDepMissing({ name, json: packageJSON }));
const notInstalled = PACKAGES.filter(name => isDepMissing({ name, json: packageLockJSON }));

console.log('the following packages are not defined:', notDefined);
console.log('the following packages are not installed:', notInstalled);
```

This will look through your `dependencies` and your `devDependencies` in both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and print anything from `PACKAGES` that can't be found.

This assumes you are using a sufficiently modern version of node so that `package-lock.json` is written.

Comment: Need to specify package.json full path?

Comment: My json path is like :     const packageJSON = readJSONFile('c:/xampp/htdocs/projects/chemis/package.json');
      const packageLockJSON = readJSONFile('c:/xampp/htdocs/projects/chemis/package-lock.json');

Comment: If you are not running the script from inside your project, then yes you'd need to specify the absolute or relative path to the files. This works for me in both scenarios. There may be something else going on, like an old node version (is the spread syntax supported), or a missing file, or a misspelled package name. You should try removing the try/catch to see if `fs.readFileSync` throws. Otherwise some simple console.log debugging should show you what's wrong.

Comment: Not working getting empty value like : the following packages are not installed:    the following packages are not installed:

Comment: getting notDefined and notInstalled is empty

Comment: If you defined `PACKAGES` to be the array of names you want to look for, and `packageJSON` and `packageLockJSON` are non-empty objects, and `notDefined` and `notInstalled` are empty arrays, then it sounds like all of the packages are both defined and installed. Try running it with a package that is is not installed.

Comment: Your script is working inside project..it is not working outside if I use const packageJSON = readJSONFile('c:/xampp/htdocs/projects/chemis/package.json');

Comment: I *think* that has to do with the way windows paths work in node. I use linux so I'm not sure, but based on [these examples](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) I think you have to write: `readJSONFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\chemis\\package.json')`. Does that work?

Comment: I think this line is problem: const deps = { ...json.dependencies, ...json.devDependencies };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198449/discussion-between-david-weldon-and-apple-orange).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NCU](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) for the same.

It has various such commands which can help you to fulfill your objective.